# Kendo Stacked Bar Chart configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have an MVC app and my controller is passing the following json data to my view

```
data:
{
    "Category":"Q1 2013",
    "Name":"Female",
    "Count":5000
},
{
    "Category":"Q1 2013",
    "Name":"Male",
    "Count":5000
}
{
    "Category":"Q1 2012",
    "Name":"Female",
    "Count":3500
},
{
    "Category":"Q1 2012",
    "Name":"Male",
    "Count":5000
}
```

I need to know how to configure my Kendo stacked bar chart to display the data like this http://jsfiddle.net/ihatemash/B6LSX/

I can't figure out how to configure the series and category to show the stacked bar chart correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is working example 
http://jsfiddle.net/idhasitha/F2TQ8/

try with like this

```
var data = [

    {"Name":1,"Year":2011,"Expense":200.00},
    {"Name":1,"Year":2012,"Expense":274.91},
    {"Name":5,"Year":2011,"Expense":100.00},
    {"Name":5,"Year":2012,"Expense":315.84},

];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        theme: "silver",
        title: {
            text: "Total records processed"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "bottom"
        },
        dataSource: {
            data: data,
            group: {
                field: "Name"
            }
        },
        transitions: false,
        series: [{
            type: "column",
            stack: "true",
            field: "Expense"
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "Year"                                
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: im very happy i thought u didnt check this