# Kendo stacked column chart not displaying data correctly

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988632/kendo-stacked-bar-chart-configuration) or similar examples I tried using kendo stacked chart.

To my suprise the chart gets displayed incorrectly.

```
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            group: {
                field: "Serie"
            }
        }),
        series:
        [{
            type: "column",
            stack: true,
            field: "Value"
        },
        ],
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "Category"
        }
    });
```

I tried defining also the model as in attached [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OmXDVwaiG1IP2nXnJN6y?p=preview) or various other variations, but the data is still incorrect e.g. 2016-07 should just show 2 activities, while it shows 5.

```
var data =
    [{ "Category": "2016-07", "Serie": "Physiotherapy", "Value": 35.00 },
        { "Category": "2016-07", "Serie": "Flex Class", "Value": 28.00 },
        { "Category": "2016-08", "Serie": "Flex Class", "Value": 27.00 },
        { "Category": "2016-08", "Serie": "Manual Therapy", "Value": 48.00 }
// rest in plunker
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. In order for this to show properly, all combinations of Category-Serie need to be served in dataSource and filled with zeros where the Serie is missing e.g. like that that

```
{ "Category": "2016-07", "Serie": "Manual Therapy", "Value": 0 }
```